# illegal pragma: {-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-incomplete-patterns #-}

Tags: haskell

i´am getting error when i am uploading the file:

```
contains illegal pragma: {-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-incomplete-patterns #-}
```

why is it wrong?

I am programing an Tree in haskell:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-incomplete-patterns #-}

module Tree where

import Test.HUnit
import Data.Char
```

Comment: Are you uploading this code? Where? It looks like the server is using an ancient GHC version. You can try removing the first line: warnings won't be enabled (which is sad) but at least in that way it might compile.

Comment: when i am removing the firt line, i get the following error:

Comment: Tree.hs:33:1: error: [-Wincomplete-patterns, -Werror=incomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for `insert':
        Patterns not matched:
            _ (Node _ (Node _ _ _) (Node _ _ _))
            _ (Node _ (Node _ _ _) Leaf)
            _ (Node _ Leaf (Node _ _ _))
            _ (Node _ Leaf Leaf)
   |
33 | insert a Leaf = Node a Leaf Leaf
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...

Comment: Perhaps the place you are uploading to doesn't want you to disable that error? You can add a catch all pattern by doing: `insert _ _ = error "catch all"`.

Comment: It looks like the server insists that all pattern matching are exhaustive. That's actually a great choice, IMO. The compiler is complaining that your `insert` function does not handle all possible cases, providing a list of missed cases. You likely have a bug in `insert`. (I didn't initially notice that your pragma *disables* the warning, so my previous comment is wrong)